# Article in biblatex with no year entry, how to remove parentheses?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

For my bibliography I am using

```
\usepackage[maxnames=99,style=alphabetic,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

I am using `@article` for arxiv papers. My problem is that I don't want to enter a year for such references. On the other hand, if I do not type in anything for the year, the generated bibliography prints () in place of the year.

How do I get rid of these parentheses?

Comment: Could you edit your post adding a [mwe](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography/4408#4408) or at least an example of the bib item (as it is in the .bib file) that gives you this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Even arxiv papers have a year and should be cited with one.

Comment: @Johannes_B I have looked at the bibliography in many math papers, and most of them do not carry a year for arXiv papers. I don't know whether the etiquette changes with the field of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `year`/`date` is a mandatory field for `@article`, `biblatex` expects there to be at least a year and does not do any further sanity checking to avoid empty brackets. We can add that with

```
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{year}} or not test {\iffieldundef{issue}}}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \iffieldundef{issue}
         {\usebibmacro{date}}
         {\printfield{issue}%
          \setunit*{\addspace}%
          \usebibmacro{date}}}}
    {}%
  \newunit}
```

---

Note though that even papers on the arXiv normally have a year (at least I have yet to happen upon a paper without a date). You should also note that an arXiv paper that has not been published in a journal (if it was published, surely it will have a date) should not be treated as an `@article`, it should rather be an `@online` entry.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works just fine! A quick question. Should I use it though? I do math, and I sometimes see arXiv articles without date, sometimes with. Honestly, it looks to me they are mostly referenced without date. Is it an etiquette that varies with the field of interest? Also, in case the work on the arxiv is also published somewhere, what date should I put for the referenced arxiv? There are 3: first submission to the arxiv, last revised on the arxiv, and the date of the publication on some journal.

Comment: @Stefano No you shouldn't. Normally all references in the bibliography should include the date, and that date should be the date of publication (of the specific version you used). An `@article` will *always* have a date, `@article`s only apply to papers published in some sort of journal and those always have a date of publishing (even online journals). Of the three or more dates on the arXiv page you should use the date of the revision you read. (Of course if you read the version in the journal, you should cite that with its publishing date and not the arXiv version.)

Comment: @Stefano I wouldn't say that the date etiquette varies with the field, I'm also in maths and would still expect all references to feature a date if possible (of course other fields are much, much stricter in their citation policies than maths.) I would like to see an example of an arXiv paper without date and of papers that don't give dates when citing them.

Comment: As for paper with arxiv without year, here is an example https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.5105v2.pdf They put the date just for the arxiv paper to appear in a journal as well.

Comment: @Stefano I have to admit, I just checked a few papers I had flying around and am horrified that I found that indeed in three of them there were references to arXiv works without date (they didn't even specify the revision they referred to). So indeed in maths it seems to be something that is sometimes done. I believe however that it is bad practice (especially if the paper has several revisions).