# How to delete parentheses for empty fields in references?

Tags: biblatex

The same question has been answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151217/remove-parentheses-for-empty-year-field-biblatex-ieee-style) but that solution does not work for me since I am not sure what is the empty field. Is there a way to drop all empty items?

Perhaps something like

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%

  if entry is empty {
             \clearfield{} 
  }
}
```

These are my attributes for biblatex:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
backref=false,
sorting=nyt,
style=authoryear,
citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

This is how the references looks:

[image]

And the .cfg which I just used as-is:

```
\ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

% Put titles in quotes for most types
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [online,article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,thesis,unpublished,patent]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{#1\addcomma}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [book]
  {title}{\mkbibemph{#1\addcomma}}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [inbook,incollection,inproceedings]
  {booktitle}{\mkbibemph{#1\addcomma}}

% Attempted Fixes for ONLINE entries
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  url = {available online at},
  }

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\printtext{accessed}\space#1}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
   \printfield{url}\addsemicolon\space
   \printurldate
  }}

% Year formatting
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
    {}
    {\printtext{%
       \printfield{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}%
\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \iffieldundef{month}
    {}
    {\printdate}}%
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{issue}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{month}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext{%
       \printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \printdate}}%
  \newunit}

% Fix names
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addperiod\space }
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{,\addspace and\addspace }

% Fix "in"
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \printtext{%
    in\space}}

% Gotta get rid of the "in" before journal title
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

% Make (Volume:Issue)
\newbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{:}%
  \printfield{number}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

% Fix editor
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{apaeditorstrg}{editor}}%
     % \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\newbibmacro*{apaeditorstrg}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{#1type}
    {\ifthenelse{\value{#1}>1\OR\ifandothers{#1}}
       {\bibstring{editors}}
       {\bibstring{editor}}}
    {\ifthenelse{\value{#1}>1\OR\ifandothers{#1}}
         {\bibcpstring{type\thefield{#1type}s}}
         {\bibcpstring{type\thefield{#1type}}}}}

% Fix appearance of , with name lists of two
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
\endinput
```

**icisfinal**

```
 \LoadClass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
```

Comment: `biblatex` already drops all formatting for empty fields if that formatting is added by the formatting directive in a `\printfield` call (this includes *most* formatting in the bibliography, but not all). In particular issuing a `\clearfield` when the field is already empty will not bring any improvement whatsoever. There are two main reasons that I can imagine for unwanted formatting remaining even though fields are empty: (1) A style relies on the presence of a mandatory field. This is the case for some settings of the standard `authoryear` style ...

Comment: ... which will show empty parentheses if the mandatory `date`/`year` is missing (cf. https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/793). In this particular case the formatting is added by an 'external' `\printtext` that can't check for emptiness of fields. Since `year`/`date` is mandatory, there is no test for emptiness of those fields. (2) The style is badly coded and does not use the usual `biblatex` idioms to format fields.

Comment: In any case it would help greatly, if you could give a concrete example of the problem you are trying to solve in the form of an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/326567/35864 helps you already. This would be the mandatory `date`/`year` issue I used as an example for case (1).

Comment: Mhhh, I have never seen something like this before. Can you turn your code snippet into a full example document (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) with `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}...\end{document}` and a relevant example `.bib` entry that reproduces the output you show when compiled in an empty folder? The output is decidedly non-standard especially if you take into account that you load the standard `authoryear` style.

Comment: @moewe thanks for your help I tried to minimize the .tex and .bib as much as I could, but I am not sure how to minimize the .cfg

Comment: Aha! I dimly remembered seeing that code before and found this older question of yours: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/476235/35864. It would have helped *greatly* if you had at least linked to that question or to the source of your `biblatex.cfg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general `biblatex` automatically drops all formatting of empty fields when the fields are printed with `\printfield`. But formatting for empty content can not be automatically dropped if it is applied by way of `\printtext` or other means. In that case the style must manually check if the contents of the `\printtext` would be empty or must (tacitly or not) assume that the contents are not empty.

It would not help at all to issue a `\clearfield` if a field is detected as empty since that would not change the state of the field in question for most relevant intents and purposes. An empty field is already cleared.

---

In your previous question [How to mention where a citation is used in the references section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/476235/35864) we established that you use the `biblatex.cfg` from https://github.com/rschuetzler/latex-icis-template/blob/master/biblatex.cfg.

Amongst other (outdated and questionable) constructions, the file contains

```
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
   \printfield{url}\addsemicolon\space
   \printurldate
  }}
```

Implicitly this code assumes that each entry has a `url` or at least a `urldate`. This assumption need not hold for many entry types. The code will always print a pair of parentheses even if the is no `url` or `urldate`.

A more sensible definition could be

```
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \iffieldundef{url}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{url}
       \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
       \printurldate}}}
```

This prints the `url` and `urldate` field in parentheses only if the `url` is present (it explicitly does not show `urldate` if there is no `url`). In particular your example entry should not show an empty pair of parentheses.

Note that this issue does not become apparent in the original template since there `biblatex` is called with the option `url=false`, which essentially means that the `url+urldate` macro is only called for `@online` entries, where a `url` field is quite probably not empty.